# JSF Composite Component binding not working

Tags: java, jsf, binding, composite-component

I'm trying to use component binding on my composite component.

```
<mylib:mycomp binding="#{bean.bindingComp}"/>
```

However, when I do this, the component is not bound. Instead, a new component is created and the already existing component in the backing bean is ignored.

Is it impossible to use component binding on a composite component? Why does this not work? When I change the component for example to

```
<h:outputText ...>
```

the binding works just fine.

Comment: Why do you want to create the component implementation of the composite programmatically in the bean in the first place? Sounds like a fishy solution for a problem which can be solved in a better way.

Comment: It doesn't work without component binding, because I need to modify the component dynamically.

Do you know why the binding doesn't work?

Comment: Just use `<c:if>` or `rendered`? Edit: I'm not sure, never used it that way because it does not make any sense.

Comment: Do you know if it works on custom components?